# traversing object graph from n-tier client

Tags: wcf, nhibernate, serialization, n-tier-architecture

I'm a student currently dabbling in a .Net n-tier app that uses Nhibernate+WCF+WPF.

One of the things that is done quite terribly is object graph serialisation, In fact it isn't done at all, currently associations are ignored and we are using DTOs everywhere.

As far as I can tell one method to proceed is to predefine which objects and collections should be loaded and serialised to go across the wire, thus being able to present some associations to the client, however this seems limited, inflexible and inconsistent (can you tell that I don't like this idea).

One option that occurred to me was to simply replace the NHProxies that lazy load collection on the client tier  with a "disconnectedProxy" that would retrieve the associated stuff over the wire. This would mean that we'd have to expand our web service signature a little and do some hackery on our generated proxies but this seemed like a good T4/other code gen experiment.

As far as I can tell this seems to be a common stumbling block but after doing a lot of reading I haven't been able to figure out any good/generally accepted solutions. I'm looking for a bit of direction as much as any particular solution, but if there is an easy way to make the client "feel" connected please let me know.

Answer (score 6):

You ask a very good question that unfortunately does not have a very clean answer.  Even if you were able to get lazy loading to work over WCF (which we were able to do) you still would have issues using the proxy interceptor.  Trust me on this one, you want POCO objects on the client tier!

What you really need to consider...what has been conceived as the industry standard approach to this problem from the research I have seen, is called *persistence vs. usage* or *persistence ignorance*.  In other words, your object model and mappings represent your persistence domain but it does not match your ideal usage scenarios.  You don't want to bring the whole database down to the client just to display a couple properties right??

It seems like such a simple problem but the solution is either very simple, or very complex.  On one hand you can design your entities around your usage scenarios but then you end up with proliferation of your object domain making it difficult to maintain.  On the other, you still want the rich object model relationships in order to write granular business logic.

To simplify this problem let’s examine the two main gaps we need to fill…between the database and the database/service layer and the service to client gap.  NHibernate fills the first one just fine by providing an ORM to load data into your objects.  It does a decent job, but in order to achieve great performance it needs to be tweaked using custom loading strategies.  I digress…

The second gap, between the server and client, is where things get dicey.  To simplify, imagine if you did not send any mapped entities over the wire to the client?  Try creating a mechanism that exchanges business entities into DTO objects and likewise DTO objects into business entities.  That way your client deals with only DTOs (POCO of course), and your business logic can maintain its rich structure.   This allows you to leverage not only NHibernate’s lazy loading mechanism, but other benefits from the session such as L1 cache.

For brevity and intellectual property reasons I will not go into the design of said mechanism, but hopefully this is enough information to point you in the right direction.  If you don’t care about performance or latency at all…just turn lazy loading off all together and work through the serialization issues.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while for me but the injection/disconnected proxies may not be as bad as it sounds. Since you are a student I am going to assume you have some time and want to muck around a bit.

If you want to inject your own custom serialization/deserialization logic you can use [IDataContractSurrogate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.idatacontractsurrogate.aspx) which can be applied using [DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.datacontractserializeroperationbehavior.aspx). I have only done a few basic things with this but it may be worth looking into. By adding some fun logic (read: potentially hackish) at this layer you might be able to make it more connected.

[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/20e5c74c-b8ee-4cc9-9c36-63210b121dd5/) is an MSDN post about someone who came to the same realization, DynamicProxy used by NHibernate makes it not possible to directly serialize NHibernate objects doing lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really determined to transport the object graph across the network and preserve lazy loading functionality.  Take a look at some code I produced over here http://slagd.com/?page_id=6 .  Basically it creates a fake session on the other side of the wire and allows the nhibernate proxies to retain their functionality. Not saying it's the right way to do things, but it might give you some ideas.